# preg_match to extract data from string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a string "CPC >= $0 (Yesterday)" and I want to get data:
`CPC`, `>=`, `0`, `Yesterday`. However the sign `>=` can vary between few more signs but is always comparison sign.

```
$str = "CPC >= $0 (Yesterday)";
preg_match('/(?<metric1>\w+) (?<sign>\w+) $(?<digit>\d+) \(((?<time>\w+))\)/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

This gives output:

```
Array
(
)
```

EDIT:

the string can also be: `CPC (Link) > $0 (Today)` the brackets before the sign. When you post the answer, can you also explain the characters used in your pattern?

(Pasted from comment...)

> I'm trying to get `CPC (Link)`, `>`, `0`, `Today` in the array --- No brackets for the last item.
>
> Yes, bracket for the first part and the comparison operators can be: `>` or `<` or `<=` or `>=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `metric1` you could list the characters you want to match in a character class and end with a whitespace and repeat that as a group.

If the `sign` part can  be `>` or `<` or `<=` or `>=` you could match those using a character class and an optional `=`

For the `digit` part you can capture the digit(s) that comes after the dollar sign in a capturing group and you have to escape the dollar sign or else its meaning would be to assert the beginning of the line.

For the `time` part you can capture all inside the parenthesis in a capturing group.

[`(?<metric1>(?:[\w()]+\s)+)(?<sign>[><]=?) \$(?<digit>\d+) \((?<time>[^)]+)\)`](https://regex101.com/r/D2a4No/1/)

**Explanation**

- `(?<metric1>` Named capturing group `metric1`

  - `(?:[\w()]+\s)+` In a non capturing group `(?=` repeat what matches in the character class followed by a whitespace and repeat that group one or more times
- `)` Close group
- `(?<sign>` Named capturing group `sign`

  - `[><]=?` Match `<` or `>` in a character class followed by an optional `=`
- `) \$` Close group and match a whitespace and a dollar sign
- `(?<digit>`

  - `\d+` Match one or more digits
- `)` Close group and match a whitespace
- `\((?<time>` Match `(` literally and start named capturing group `time`

  - `[^)]+` Match not a closing parenthesis using a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)
- `)\)` Close group and match `)` literally

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/k1TTT)

Comment: Can you also tell me how I can set pattern for optional word? like in case of `CPC (Link) > $0 (Today) and` -- `and` is optional.

Comment: and can you give me link to learn this easily. i tried php.net but the explanation is very difficult.

Comment: @Prakash1 You could take a look at [character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), [grouping](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html). You could also take a look at  [this webiste](http://www.rexegg.com/). To make ` and` optional you might use an optional non capturing group to match a whitespace and one or more word characters `(?: \w+)?` as in [this example](https://regex101.com/r/zrz3HA/1).

Comment: @Prakash1 Because you are specifying a semicolon `(?<andor>: \w+)?`. Try it [like this](https://regex101.com/r/zrz3HA/2).

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues:

- >, = etc. are not word characters (matched by \w). You need to use
  \S (any non-whitespace character) instead.
- You need to escape the $ sign (otherwise it tries to match end of
  string).
- You have more ()'s around `time` than you need

Try this instead:

```
$regex = '/(?<metric1>\w+(\s\([^)]+\))?)\s+(?<sign>\S+)\s+\$(?<digit>\d+)\s+\((?<time>[^)]+)\)/';
$str = "CPC >= $0 (Yesterday)";
preg_match($regex, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
$str = "CPC (Link) > $0 (Today)";
preg_match($regex, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => CPC >= $0 (Yesterday)
    [metric1] => CPC
    [1] => CPC
    [2] => 
    [sign] => >=
    [3] => >=
    [digit] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [time] => Yesterday
    [5] => Yesterday
)
Array
(
    [0] => CPC (Link) > $0 (Yesterday)
    [metric1] => CPC (Link)
    [1] => CPC (Link)
    [2] =>  (Link)
    [sign] => >
    [3] => >
    [digit] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [time] => Today
    [5] => Today
)
```

An explanation of `$regex`:

```
(?<metric1>\w+(\s\([^)]+\))?) - captures a word (\w+) followed by an optional set of characters within () into a group called metric
(?<sign>\S+) - captures a sequence of non-whitespace characters (\S+) into a group called sign
\$(?<digit>\d+) - captures a sequence of digits (\d+) following a $ sign into a group called digit
\((?<time>[^)]+) - captures a set of characters within () into a group called time
```

Comment: Please check the edit, The sign can vary, how can use use multiple options there

Comment: Did you want to capture (Link) with CPC or separately?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which works with your example :

```
$str = "CPC >= $0 (Yesterday)";
preg_match_all("/[^\s$)(]+/", $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
// Array ( [0] => CPC [1] => >= [2] => 0 [3] => Yesterday )
```

Comment: Edited. This regex currently matches every expressions not containing spaces, parenthesis and dollars. So it works with your 2 examples.

Comment: Yes, but the string before `>` sign is one string. I'm trying to get `CPC (Link)`, `>`, `0`, `Today` in the array --- No brackets for the last item, Yes bracket for the first part and the `>` can be `>` or `<` or `<=` or `>=`

Answer (score 0):

I never use named capture groups because they make the pattern harder to read and they bloat the output array.  If you want to generate named variables, you can use `list()` or [Symmetric Array Destructuring](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php).

If it were my project, I probably wouldn't name the capture groups or the variables, but if it makes your code more readable or comprehensible that is a noble-enough reason.

- Just remember that the first element in the output array is the fullstring match, which you have no use for.

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kRBzWa/2)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/pjsBE))

```
$strings = [
    'CPC >= $0 (Yesterday)',
    'CPC (Link) > $100 (Today)'
];

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    list($metric, $sign, $digit, $time) = preg_match('~([\w ()]+) ([><]=?) \$(\d+) \(([^)]+)\)~', $string, $out) ? array_slice($out, 1) : ['', '', '', ''];  // if fails, use empty strings

    echo "metric: $metric, sign: $sign, digit: $digit, time: $time\n";
    var_export($metric);  // notice no leading or trailing spaces / unwanted characters in the output
    echo "\n";
    var_export($sign);    // notice no leading or trailing spaces / unwanted characters in the output
    echo "\n";
    var_export($digit);   // notice no leading or trailing spaces / unwanted characters in the output
    echo "\n";
    var_export($time);    // notice no leading or trailing spaces / unwanted characters in the output
    echo "\n----------\n";
}
```

Output:

```
metric: CPC, sign: >=, digit: 0, time: Yesterday
'CPC'
'>='
'0'
'Yesterday'
----------
metric: CPC (Link), sign: >, digit: 100, time: Today
'CPC (Link)'
'>'
'100'
'Today'
----------
```

Pattern Breakdown:

```
~            #starting pattern delimiter
(            #start of Capture Group #1
  [\w ()]+   #match (as much as possible) 1 or more A-Z, a-z, 0-9, _, space, or parenthesis (in any order)
)            #end of Capture Group #1
 (           #match space then start of Capture Group #2
   [><]=?    #match greater than or less than symbol followed optionally by equals symbol
 )           #end of Capture Group #2
 \$          #match space then a dollar symbol (backslash tells regex to treat the dollar sign literally)
(            #start of Capture Group #3
  \d+        #match one or more digits
)            #end of Capture Group #3
 \(          #match space then opening parenthesis (made literal by backslash)
(            #start of Capture Group #4
  [^)]+      #match one or more characters that are not a closing parenthesis
)            #end of Capture Group #4
\)           #match closing parenthesis literally
~            #end pattern delimiter
```